# kivy -- event for when guis is loaded

Tags: python, kivy

How can I register a callback for when a Kivy gui is loaded?

In my Kivy app, as soon as the GUI is loaded (aka the window pops up with the initial view), I need to kick off a function that loads expensive data and updates the UI.

So far i've been using the `on_start` method in `App` but this runs before the GUI is loaded.

essentially, i want something like `$( document ).ready()` (from jquery) but for ivy

Answer (score 0):

You could Clock.schedule(some_function, 0) in your build method, I think that would run after everything is initialised but before the next frame.

Comment: that might work. i ended up starting a thread in `on_start` that did the work I needed. that let the GUI run while effectually starting initialization right away. Thanks!

Comment: AttributeError: 'ClockBase' object has no attribute 'schedule'